# Opening multiple text files ofstream

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I want to open multiple text files and store the streams as a vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

vector<string> imgSet
vector<ofstream> txtFiles;

// .
// .

    for( int i=0 ; i<imgSet.size() ; i++ )
    {
            ofstream s;
            s.open( imgSet[i].getName(), std::ofstream::out );
            txtFiles.push_back( s );
    }

}
```

getName looks like :

```
const string& getName() const;
```

I am compiling this with G++ on ubuntu, I don't understand why I get a long list of errors with it. How can this be fixed

Comment: What's `imgSet[i].getName()`?  `std::string` has no member function `getName()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no operator= or copy constructor in std::fstream in C++03.
You can do this:

```
vector<ofstream*> txtFiles;
//...
for( int i=0 ; i<imgSet.size() ; i++ )
{
        txtFiles.push_back( new ofstream(imgSet[i].getName(), std::ofstream::out) );
}
```

Comment: then, how can i achieve my objective of creating multiple files?

Comment: @mkuse I added an example how you can achieve this.

Comment: does not seem to work, just added declaration for getName() in my question

Comment: If you're going to suggest juggling a collection of raw pointers, then at least mention that they must be deleted (even if you do sweep the exception-safety nightmare under the carpet and pretend `new ofstream` can't fail). Smart pointers (`unique_ptr` since C++11, `boost::shared_ptr` if you're stuck in the past) would be much better.

Comment: @MikeSeymour  I'm stuck in embedded ARM's :) But you're right, of course - never forget about deleting dynamically allocated objects and about error management.

Answer (score 2):

The various iostream classes are neither copiable nor assignable.  In
pre-C++11, elements of a vector must be both.  About the only solution
is to use a vector of `std::ofstream*` (probably wrapped in a class to
ensure proper deletion).

In C++11, the iostream classes have been made movable, and vector has
been extended to allow movable members.  So you could write something
like:

```
for ( std::string const& fileName : imgSet )
    txtFiles.emplace_back( fileName );
```

This supposes more or less C++11 support; I don't know the status of
g++, but this doesn't pass with the version I'm using (4.8.3).  I think
it's more a problem of the library than the compiler, and it might work
with a more recent version of the library.  (Don't forget to compile
with `-std=c++11`.)